# Run a script on monitor connection/disconnection event

Tags: linux, event-handling, multiple-monitors, udev

I read many threads about how to do this and yet it doesn't work for me.

What I want to achieve is:

When my laptop has 2 additional displays connected when I close its lid, I don't want it to go to sleep. However, if I disconnect the displays and the lid is closed, I want to put the laptop to sleep (this way, not forgetting it on).

---

Therefore, I created a BASH script that should be executed on VGA / HDMI  connection events. The BASH script counts how many displays are connected and if there's only 1, it will put the laptop to sleep when the lid is closed.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. This is what I've done so far:

- Created 2 files: `displays_count_sleep.sh` and `on_hdmi_connected.rules`
  https://gist.github.com/nbtk123/9ffbf7541e47b9c0015f5c3e9f44b7c9
- Put this **on_hdmi_connected.rules** into `/etc/udev/rules.d` to catch the event:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", RUN+="/bin/bash /home/nir/dev/scripts/displays_count_sleep.sh"
```

- Put the bash script I want to run, **displays_count_sleep.sh**, into `/home/nir/dev/scripts`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

DISPLAYS_NUM=2

`touch test`

display_count=`xrandr -d :0 -q | grep ' connected' | wc -l`

echo "display count="$display_count
echo "display_num="$DISPLAYS_NUM

if [ "$display_count" -ge "$DISPLAYS_NUM" ]; then
    echo "nothing"
    `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action nothing`
    `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action nothing`
else
    echo "sleep"
    `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action suspend`
    `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action suspend`
fi
```

Both files have been created as root. When running "`udevadm test`", the output is as in the file '**udevadm_test_output**' on the link.

I don't know if the event is catched, but on the real monitor (dis)connection, the script doesn't run. It works okay if I run it manually.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145342/disabling-monitor-reconfiguration-when-closing-lid, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev The event I want to catch is the HDMI / VGA connections, not he close lid

Comment: Sorry. The formulations are somewhat messy so I got confused which event you cannot catch. The trigger was incorrect usage of "DRM" (the tag relates to its other meaning).

Comment: Backticks aren't needed except when you're catching the output into a variable.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Didn't understand what did you mean in the last comment?

Comment: Why don't you know if the event is catched... Why not create a file on the event so you can check if event has been catched?

Comment: @LuisColorado I tried to use 'touch' in the RUN string. Didn't work =\

Comment: @nbtk, so you are answering yourself.

Comment: @LuisColorado Not quite. I still don't know how to fix the event catching... I run 'udevadm monitor', and the parameters I listen to are correct. (subsystem=drm). I also tried with action=change. Just doesn't work